# Concurrent insertion in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a loop in which I first create 1 objects and the next object uses the id from the previous inserted object.

The problem is that sometimes it seems it's not finished inserting the previous object before it started the next insertion, so the last insertion doesn't get the id from the previous insertion.

I guess it's Meteor creating things concurrently instead of stop waiting for other operations to finish before moving on.

How can I make sure the previous insertion is finished before moving on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on the server or client? For server if you don't provide a callback the methods should run synchronized, for client you must provide a callback and you should get the id in the callback returned data. If you need to have them synced you can use Meteor's wrapAsync method, more info here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync

Comment: I do it on the server. I'm inserting with `group = Groups.insert({name: "A"}); element = Elements.insert({groupId: group._id});`. How can I wrap these function, so I am sure the group was inserted before inserting the element?

Comment: When you do Elements.insert the groupId param should be only "group", NOT group._id . Insert returns the object id, not the object itself, check http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert - "Insert a document in the collection. Returns its unique _id."

Comment: And no need to wrapAsync since you are on the server, the calls are synced. Your code is fine, except for that extra ._id :)